# how to reorder columns in pyarrow table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyarrow

I have pyarrow table which have column order ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] I want to change the order of this pyarrow table to ['B', 'D', 'C', 'A'] can we reorder pyarrows table like pandas dataframe ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pyarrow.Table.select`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.Table.html#pyarrow.Table.select)

```py
import pyarrow as pa

table_a_b  = pa.table({
    "A": [1,2,3],
    "B": [4,5,6]
})

table_b_a = table_a_b.select(['B', 'A'])
```

| B | A |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

cols = ['B', 'A']
df = df[cols]

| B | A |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |